# pygeocoder for python error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using city and state to generate coordinates, which is then used to calculate distance between 2 points.   I use pygeocoder to generate the coordinates of a city/state.  Occasionally I get a generic Google error (which is what pygoecoder uses) and that breaks the process and forces me to restart the process on my entire dataset. It usually works when I try again. I'm not that familiar with "vectorize", but can I use try/except for the Geocoder call to stop it from breaking without interfering with vectorize?

Separate question.  Pygeocoder generates another, more meaningful, error;  OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.  Is there another library that maybe does not have a query limit, or an API authentication can be used to increase the query limit?

```
import pandas as pd
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

def geocoder(city, state):
  print(city,state)
  coords = Geocoder.geocode("{0}, {1}".format(city, state)).coordinates                         
  lat, long = coords
  R = 6373.0
  lat1 = radians(lat)
  lon1 = radians(long)
  lat2 = radians(38.978443)
  lon2 = radians(-76.492180) 
  dlon = lon2 - lon1 
  dlat = lat2 - lat1
  a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2 
  c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
  distance = R * c
  return distance

players['distance'] = np.vectorize(geocoder)(players['City'], players['State'])
```

Comment: Over query limit is a thing.  Google gives you 1000 calls/24 hours (almost) anonymously.  If you prove who you are by providing a credit card (they say they won't charge you, and they haven't charged mine), they give you 150000 calls in 24 hours.  This might be your simplest solution.

Comment: There is a geocoding service called geonames which may have fewer restrictions on api calls - not sure.